# Android compose navigation - how can I pass url type of argument?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing the Firebase Email Link Auth sample using Jetpack Compose & Navigation.

If user input email and try authentication, an email is sent to the email.
When the user open and click the email's link, the app is again opened.

It uses Firebase dynamic link.

So, when the app is opened again, I can get the `emailLink` from the dynamic link.
And I pass it to the destination page (Home).

```kotlin
Firebase.dynamicLinks
    .getDynamicLink(intent)
    .addOnSuccessListener(this@MainActivity) { pendingDynamicLinkData: PendingDynamicLinkData? ->
        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
            val emailLink = intent?.data?.toString()
            if (emailLink != null && firebaseAuth.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)) {
                intent = null
                navController.navigate("${Home.route}?emailLink={$emailLink}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My NavHost code is:

```kotlin
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Home.route,
) {
    composable(
        route = "${Home.route}?emailLink={emailLink}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("emailLink") {
            type = NavType.StringType
            nullable = true
            defaultValue = null
        })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        val emailLink = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("emailLink")
        Log.i("TEST", "[sample] navigate - emailLink: $emailLink")
        HomeScreen(
            vm = hiltViewModel(),
            emailLink = emailLink
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is...
The original `emailLink` is :

```
https://email-link-auth-sample-95a4a.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=AIzaSyD2w6bRHiqEXaSx9W0N5Mq5obydIjRk_mw&mode=signIn&oobCode=dj8M6b4Rq6dwM81ziExyw_3-gXiExQY8FvHNAZsPDxMAAAGETZgg0w&continueUrl=https://emaillinkauthsample.page.link&lang=en
```

But when I get it from the `backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("emailLink")`,
the `emailLink` is :

```
{https://email-link-auth-sample-95a4a.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=AIzaSyD2w6bRHiqEXaSx9W0N5Mq5obydIjRk_mw
```

I think that the compose navigation system was designed based on the url system.
So in this case, it works incorrectly.

Is there any good solution...?

Actually, I wrote the code using the `savedStateHandle`, and it works fine.

```kotlin
Firebase.dynamicLinks
    .getDynamicLink(intent)
    .addOnSuccessListener(this@MainActivity) { pendingDynamicLinkData: PendingDynamicLinkData? ->
        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
            val emailLink = intent?.data?.toString()
            if (emailLink != null && firebaseAuth.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)) {
                intent = null

                // navController.navigate("${Home.route}?emailLink={$emailLink}")

                /**
                 * my workaround code using the `savedStateHandle`
                 */
                navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.apply {
                  set("emailLink", emailLink)
                }
                navController.navigate(Home.route)
            }
        }
    }
}

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Home.route,
) {
    composable(
        route = "${Home.route}?emailLink={emailLink}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("emailLink") {
            type = NavType.StringType
            nullable = true
            defaultValue = null
        })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        // val emailLink = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("emailLink")

        /**
         * my workaround code using the `savedStateHandle`
         */
        val emailLink = navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<String>("emailLink")
        HomeScreen(
            vm = hiltViewModel(),
            emailLink = emailLink
        )
    }
}
```

You can find the code in here: https://github.com/yoonhok524/Email-Link-Auth-Sample

Comment: So you say that what you receive is incomplete and starts with `{`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue.
If I encode the url link and then pass it, it works fine!

```kotlin
Firebase.dynamicLinks
    .getDynamicLink(intent)
    .addOnSuccessListener(this@MainActivity) { pendingDynamicLinkData: PendingDynamicLinkData? ->
        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
            val emailLink = intent?.data?.toString()
            if (emailLink != null && firebaseAuth.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)) {
                intent = null

                // navController.navigate("${Home.route}?emailLink={$emailLink}")


                /**
                 * my workaround code using the `savedStateHandle`
                 */
                // navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.apply {
                //   set("emailLink", emailLink)
                // }
                // navController.navigate(Home.route)


                /**
                 * my solution code
                 */
                val encodedEmailLink = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                  URLEncoder.encode(it, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
                }
                navController.navigate(Home.getRoute(encodedEmailLink))
            }
        }
    }
}
```